# jQuery - Hide and Show <div> on Unique Button Hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I basically just want to populate a div with text based on what button is being rolled over using jQuery. I'm not quite sure where I went wrong.

```
        $(".buttonSet").hover(function(){
        if $("#button_X".hover){
            $('.textPreview').show();
            document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = 'TEST X';
        } if else $("#button_Y".hover) {
            $('.textPreview').show();
            document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = 'TEST Y';
        } if else $("#button_Z".hover) {
            $('.textPreview').show();
            document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = 'TEST Z';
        }
    },function(){
        $('.textPreview').hide();
    });
```

Comment: (a) What's the error? (b) Can you post a working example in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something simpler and easier to maintain...
In each of your buttons assign the function to show/hide your div to the onmouseover and onmouseleave events. You can pass a different message to the function as the parameter.

```
function ShowOutput(message){
   $('#output').show().text(message + ' was button hovered');
}
```

your HTML would look something like:

```
<div id="buttonX" class="button" onmouseover="ShowOutput('X')" onmouseleave="$('#output').hide()">X</div>
<div id="buttonY" class="button" onmouseover="ShowOutput('Y')" onmouseleave="$('#output').hide()">Y</div>
<div id="buttonZ" class="button" onmouseover="ShowOutput('Z')" onmouseleave="$('#output').hide()">Z</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Take a look at this Plunker I created for you:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sli9hQIF0glc3Nvaxkwu?p=info

P.S Make sure you add jQuery to your html page if you want to use jQuery code.

Comment: Ah I didn't know where was an onmouseleave thing. Totally gonna use this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use separate hover events for each button? It will simplify your code and possibly fix your problem:

```
$("#button_X").hover(function(){
    $('.textPreview').show();
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = 'TEST X';
});

$("#button_Y").hover(function(){
    $('.textPreview').show();
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = 'TEST Y';
});

$("#button_Z").hover(function(){
    $('.textPreview').show();
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = 'TEST Z';
});
```

Comment: Ah that totally helps! Now how would you handle hiding the buttons when the user isn't hoving them?